# Unable to execute other Python scripts (using SQLAlchemy) from the initial script

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am relatively new to Python and is stuck with an issue related to the execution of different Python modules which is regarding creation of database schema using `Base.metadata.create_all(engine)` command in `SQLAlchemy`.

In the root directory of my application, I have a Python file named `app.py` and a Python module folder named `models`. The `models` directory contains different Python scripts for different models corresponding to their database tables using `SQLAlchemy`, for eg `user.py`, `post.py`, etc.

I am using `Base.metadata.create_all(engine)` in the `app.py` to create database schema, but as the models are defined in separate files, the initial `app.py` script is unable to run those files and a blank database is created without any tables.

`app.py` looks like this:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///db.sqlite3', echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

What I think is when I execute `app.py` script, it is unable to find the model files (used to create tables) in the `models` directory. So, what is the way that those model files are also executed along with the `app.py` file so that the `Base.metadata.create_all(engine)` command executes properly?

Please let me know if my question is not clear and/or I am missing some basic concept about Python modules and scripts.

Comment: Have you imported the `models` module in `app`?

Comment: No, because if I import the `models` module in `app.py`, they will be used nowhere in the code. Or, let me know if this is acceptable to just write an `import` statement and use the imported file/module nowhere in the code?